# How to check if time is next day

Tags: c#, .net

I have a windows application where user enters Start Time and End Time, How to check if End time is next day time.

```
example: start time           end time
          1:00:00 AM          5:00:00 AM
          5:00:00 AM          10:00:00 AM
          10:00:00 AM          5:00:00 PM
          5:00:00 PM          10:00:00 PM
          10:00:00 PM          1:00:00 AM --(next day)
          1:00:00 AM          5:00:00 AM
```

I am trying something like below:

```
private void GenerateReportWithStartTimeandEndTime(string StartTime, string EndTime, string DailyTime)
{
    DateTime tempStartTime = DateTime.ParseExact(StartTime, "HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DateTime tempEndTime = DateTime.ParseExact(EndTime, "HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    DateTime midNightToday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
    var StarthourDifference = (midNightToday - tempStartTime).TotalHours;
    var EndhourDifference = (midNightToday - tempEndTime).TotalHours;
    if (StarthourDifference - EndhourDifference > 0)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: If all you have is bare time values, the only logic you can apply is to check whether the end value is less than the start value and *assume* that this means the next day. If that's not what you want to do, you need to explain how we (and the computer) are meant to magically determine this when there doesn't appear to be enough information.

Comment: Start and end time of *what* exactly?

Comment: start and end time of a day

Comment: For the 1AM-5AM interval, how do you know it's not 5AM *a day later*?

Comment: yeah your point make sense, thanks Hans. I should think about it now may be it will solve my problem

Comment: Using specific time-of-days to define duration is just wrong. You either use whole datetimes (with the date part, which you can hide if needed in the UI), or you define a time of day for a start and a task *duration*, not a time-of-day of end (that can be calculated taking the duration if you need to show that to your users). This specification can fall down to pieces easily.

Answer (score 5):

how about

```
bool IsNextDay = EndTime < StartTime;
```

Code:

```
//case 1
TimeSpan StartTime = DateTime.ParseExact("5:00:00 PM", "h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan EndTime = DateTime.ParseExact("10:00:00 PM", "h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
bool IsNextDay = EndTime < StartTime; //false

//case 2
TimeSpan StartTime2 = DateTime.ParseExact("10:00:00 PM", "h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan EndTime2 = DateTime.ParseExact("1:00:00 AM", "h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
bool IsNextDay2 = EndTime2 < StartTime2; //true
```

Comment: Might also be `<=`, depending on whether 0 hours or 24 hours should be the interpretation if the two times are equal.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen while the comment is right, the whole OPs specification comes down to pieces if the time difference can be 24 hours (it's already bad, but if time diffs can be 24hr or more, it gets as bad as it can get :-) )

Comment: I know all about "as bad as it can get", I deal with dates and times in our software every day and have to deal with these exact issues, *including* time-only data that span more than two dates.

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine :

For a time to be on next day (since the difference is always 5 hrs), if the end parse time in `hh:mm:ss tt` format is less begin parsed time, then it is a next day time.

```
var t1 = "10:00:00 PM";
var t2 = "01:00:00 AM";

var time1 = DateTime.ParseExact(t1, "hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var time2 = DateTime.ParseExact(t2, "hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

if (time2 < time1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("next day");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("same day");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a condition like this: (startDate > EndDate) and
(EndDate - startDate) > 24 hours